# Divisibility and number theory in terms of a and b

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, coprime

Are there infinitely many pairs of $(a, b)$ of relatively prime integers $a > 1$ and $b > 1$ such that $a^b+b^a$ is divisible by $a+b$?

I've spent almost two hours on this question to no avail. The small cases I have tried, such as $(3, 5)$, $(3, 7)$ and $(5, 7)$ all work, so I'm conjecturing that the answer is yes. However, all methods of proof I have tried have failed. Tried modulo arguments but can't really simplify my results.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show in detail an example/examples of your attempted proofs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sil posted a now deleted almost correct answer, so this is based on those ideas. (The answer has since been undeleted and corrected)

Let $a=2k-1$, $b=2k+1$ for any integer $k$. $a,b$ are coprime. $a+b=4k$.

Note that 
$$ab=4k^2-1 \equiv -1 \pmod{4k},$$
$$a^2 = 4k^2 - 4k +1 \equiv 1 \pmod {4k},$$
$$b^2 = 4k^2 + 4k +1 \equiv 1 \pmod {4k}.$$
Since $ab\equiv -1\pmod{4k}$, $b^{-1} \equiv -a\pmod{4k}$.

Then 
$$
a^b+b^a
=a^{2k+1}+b^{2k-1}
\equiv 
a^1 + b^{-1}
\equiv
a-a
=0\pmod{4k}.
$$

Thus $a^b+b^a \equiv 0\pmod{a+b}$, so $a+b\mid a^b+b^a$.

Hence we have found infinitely many such pairs.

Comment: Nice, this is more elegant then my (now hopefully fixed) argument (I had to use binomial theorem to get from $2k$ modulus to $4k$).

Comment: @Sil The binomial theorem argument is also pretty nice, (+1)

Answer (score 4):

Sure, choose for example $a=2k-1,b=2k+1$ for any integer $k$. Clearly these pairs are coprime, and we have

\begin{align}
a^b+b^a&=(2k-1)^{2k+1}+(2k+1)^{2k-1}\\
&\equiv -1+(2k+1)2k+1+(2k-1)2k\tag{*}\\
&=8k^2\\
&\equiv 0 \pmod{4k}.
\end{align}

where $(*)$ follows from Binomial theorem for example (or see jgon's answer for alternative argument). So $a^b+b^a \equiv 0 \bmod {a+b}$ since $a+b=4k$.